# Htaccess configuration to start from sub-folder instead of root

Tags: php, .htaccess

**I have a site www.domain.com , and i built my mvc framework for it.
.htaccess file content as following:**

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$l [QSA,L]
```

---

it makes me able to navigate like www.domain.com/home/index/ correctly, but i need to re-configure it to read from www.domain.com/site , instead of the end of domain.com ?!
any help ?

Comment: Whats `site` and how is `home/index/` correctly? Dont you want it just `www.domain.com` which points to the project?

Comment: Your also using `l` not `1` for `$l`

Comment: i have many projects on the same domain, and the mvc project must run from a sub folder , my htaccess is only runs correctly when it is in the root of my domain and i don't know how to reconfigure it to run it from a sub folder in my domain

Comment: You need a rewrite in the root which points to the correct path or points to the second rewrite (which saves you fixing it again when putting it live), or use a vhost which matches `/site`..

Comment: any way i have a solution by php and i already done it but it i was wondering if it can be solved by htaccess.

Comment: Whats that? Id be interested to know.

Comment: i made 2 constants first with the full domain name and the second with sub-folder name and added  them where it needs ;) but i am sure that there is a more flexible solution in htaccess but i don't know how to write htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

add this line:

```
Redirect /index.html /public/
```

and it will redirect to public folder , or change the word to any path you want.